# Rubymotion translation of SendBird SDK methods

Tags: rubymotion, sendbird

I am working on a SendBird chat integration with Rubymotion. I am running into some problems since I am unable to get a Messaging Channel List from the SDK due to my limited knowledge of Objective-C / Swift structures.

I would appreciate some help translating the following code into RubyMotion code:

Objective-C:

```
- (void) queryMessagingChannels
{
    messagingChannelListQuery = [SendBird queryMessagingChannelList];
    [messagingChannelListQuery setLimit:15];
    [messagingChannelListQuery nextWithResultBlock:^(NSMutableArray *queryResult) {
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < [queryResult count]; i++) {
            SendBirdMessagingChannel *mc = (SendBirdMessagingChannel *)[queryResult objectAtIndex:i];
            ...
        }
        ...
    } endBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    }];
}
```

Swift:

```
func queryMessagingChannels() {
    messagingChannelListQuery = SendBird.queryMessagingChannelList()
    messagingChannelListQuery?.setLimit(15)
    messagingChannelListQuery?.nextWithResultBlock({ (queryResult) -> Void in
        ....
        for model in queryResult {
            let mc: SendBirdMessagingChannel = model as! SendBirdMessagingChannel
            ....
        }
        ....
        }, endBlock: { (code) -> Void in
    })
}
```

So far I have this, but it is failing with an error.

Rubymotion:

```
mp "Iterating over MessagingChannelList"
@messagingChannelListQuery = SendBird.queryMessagingChannelList()
@messagingChannelListQuery.setLimit(5)
@messagingChannelListQuery.nextWithResultBlock.each do |queryResult|
  @messaging_channels << queryResult
end
# reload tableview data here
```

Error:

```
chat_messaging_screen.rb:49:in `load_async': undefined method `nextWithResultBlock' for #<SendBirdMessagingChannelListQuery:0x117c672e0> (NoMethodError)
```

I really don't know how to properly set up the block in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the nextWithResultBlock actually requires passing endBlock too, so this finally solved it:

```
@messagingChannelListQuery.nextWithResultBlock(
  -> (queryresult) {
  #do something here with queryresult.each
  },
  endBlock: -> (code) {
  }
)
```

The NoMethodError was throwing me off.